# Lots of bad sectors on a new SSD drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, smart, bad-sectors

I have a two week old laptop with a 128GB SSD. After a week during (presumably) the first fsck job run on the machine, I got a load of short read errors.

After allowing fsck to fix the errors, I installed the smartmontools and got something like the following output (the problem occurred last week but I've been trying to figure out what to do by myself so this is the output from today).

I seem to have a load of bad sectors, plus a large reported_uncorrect count. I also ran some of the tests which exited because of bad blocks. Based on all this, do you think my drive is going to fail?

Thanks in advance!

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.2.0-23-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SD7SN3Q128G1002
Serial Number:    145111401252
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 cd4e53f24
Firmware Version: X2170002
User Capacity:    128,035,676,160 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      < 1.8 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jan 18 23:05:05 2016 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       31
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   082   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       82
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       89
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       61
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       19
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       418
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       878
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   066   045   ---    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 12/45)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       3
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       207
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       133
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       360
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 824 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 824 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  51 40 02 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 823 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  51 40 02 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 822 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  51 40 02 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 821 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  51 40 02 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 820 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  51 40 02 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       00%        64         1881328
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        64         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       00%        53         1881328

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: Yes it is failing, back up important files and replace the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I guess I'll replace it then!

Comment: OK. So I took my laptop into the store and they ran their own test software which said that the SSD drive was fine so they wouldn't replace it. Is it possible that the errors are a result of software when running linux on the laptop (it originally came with windows)?

Comment: Run memtest from a bootable usb...http://www.memtest.org/